# How to split the comma separated list in the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, t-sql

I am working on small module in which we pass the column name as comma-separated string to a stored procedure. In the stored procedure, we want to separate the column names out.

Comment: This is literally the definition of a "give me the code" post. There are dozens or thousands of a script like this all over the web. In the future, please share with us your research and concerns, rather than just blanket asking for the code.

Answer (score 5):

The definitive article on the topic is [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) which contains code and performance test results for a variety of split functions.

You say these are column names? You should probably read another of Erland's articles on [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) where he discusses both SQL injection and when dynamic SQL is a good idea.